# how to get modified time of file using sharepoint web services in java

Tags: java, web-services, file, sharepoint

I want to get modified time of a specific file using web services.
There are two web services i am familiar with:
1. `copy web service` - it return file content and metadata. i can't use it as i need only the modified date field without the file content and other metadata fields.
2. `lists web service` - i'm not sure if i can use it so it would return modified date of only one file and not multiple files.

What should i use?
Is there another web service for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

You execute a GET HTTP-Request for your first "web service". Better say: "I send a GET request to my webservice to get the file content together with the metadata".
If you only need the metadata (without the file content) the normal HTTP way of doing it is a HEAD HTTP-Request. I do not know how to do this with "your" webservice, because you do not provide detailed information about it.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your comment!
my question is on share point web services, i want to get a metadata on file located in share Point using the web services share Point offer, from my software.

Answer (score 0):

Use the site data(`http://<Site>/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx`) web service.
In this service use the `getListItems` method to get the file details.

**Reference:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774532%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774821%28v=office.12%29.asp